# Unable to customize tables with jquery-datatables to sort/filter/order at display side

Tags: python, html, datatables, flask-appbuilder

I have a html file to render my table using a flask app. It works fine and I'd like to add some customization using datatables.

I'm really unsure where in the jQuery portion to add the customization.  My code has it in the html file, but I don't see the customization working when I run it. Should it be a static/js/jquery.js file in my projects folder? I have datatables downloaded, but I don't see the result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#queues').dataTable();
    });
  </script>
  <script

src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> // 
JQuery Reference

<script

src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">    
</script>
<script

src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug- 
 ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet"

href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery- 
 ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet"

 href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plugins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/
  jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css">

  <style type="text/css">
body {
  background: seashell;
  color: black;
}
div.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 20px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
  </style>
  <title>{{ title }} - Queues</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <h2>Page for Queues display </h2>
    <p style="color:blue;">Queues information</p>
    <table border="1">
      <th style="text-align:left;">Job</th>
  <th style="text-align:left;">Team</th>
  <th style="text-align:left;">Problem</th>
  <th style="text-align:left;">CPU</th>
  <th style="text-align:left;">Memory</th>
  {% for row in data%}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ row[0] }}</td> <td>{{ row[1] }}</td> <td>{{ row[2] }}</td> <td>{{ row[3] }}</td> <td>{{ row[4] }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I get the table with data displayed properly but not the customization. I followed instructions in this example: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/844403/%2FTips%2F844403%2FjQuery-Datatables-For-Beginners

Answer (score 1):

I have found in the past that when using data tables, that if you don't include the `<tbody>` and `<thead>` tags in your table, the table won't show up as a datable. Those are shown in the link you have sent, but not in your code.

Comment: thanks, I changed that! It looks like a normal table though. I wonder how to identify whether this is a data table.

Comment: There appears to be an initialisation code  `$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').dataTable();
} );` I added it as a .js file but I don't see the features of datatables enabled.

Comment: you need to add the id that you used to initialize it to the table. So in this case your table should have an id of `example`. So `<table id="example" border="1">`